# Youtube Permanent LiveStream URL

Tags: youtube, live-streaming

I've got 2 concurrent live-streams happening under the same account (different stream keys), both of which will be streaming longer than 12 hours.

I currently have `https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[CHANNEL_ID_HERE]` to grab the permanent embed stream.

However - is there a URL parameter to grab the second live-stream, and not just the first?

Thanks!